# Which Qt Creator is compatible with Qt4?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, mitk

I am finding to install Qt4 instead of the latest Qt5.5.

This is due to forward compatibility issues with Qt5.5 and the [Medical Interaction toolkit library MITK](http://mitk.org/wiki/MITK).

I have located the [download archive](http://download.qt.io/archive/) of Qt. But, does anyone know which version of Qt Creator is compatible with Qt4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sides of compatibility here:

1. The range of Qt versions you can build Qt Creator with: That's at least Qt 5.0, and possibly higher.

   Qt Creator 3.2.2 is the last version that could be built with Qt 4. From Qt Creator 3.3 onwards, only Qt 5 is supported.
2. The range of Qt versions that you can add to Qt Creator and its kits: That's at least Qt 4.0, possibly higher but 4.7 works for sure.

So, you should use the latest Qt Creator, and simply download and build Qt 4.8 that suits your needs, and then add it to Qt Creator.

Comment: Just in case if someone is interested in which is the latest Qt Creator you can *build* and not just use with Qt 4 - it is Qt Creator 3.2.2. Starting with Qt Creator 3.3 support for compiling it with Qt 4 [was dropped](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/12/10/qt-creator-3-3-0-released/).

Comment: @Wildcat Thank you.